# Relate l1 norm of Hadamard product to trace

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, trace, hadamard-product

Suppose $A$ is a $q\times p$ matrix, $B$ is $q \times p$ matrix, $A_j$ is the jth column of $A$, and $B_j$ is the jth column of $B$.  The following sum of  $l_1$ norms, where "$\circ$" is the Frobenius norm

$\sum_{j=1}^p |A_j \circ B_j|$

gives the sum of the absolute values of the components of $A \circ B$, the Hadamard product of matrices $A$ and $B$.  I am trying to relate this to a trace.  I know that

$\sum_{i=1}^q \sum_{j=1}^p (A \circ B)_{ij} = trace(A \cdot B^\top) = trace(B \cdot A^\top)$

where $A^\top$ is the transpose of $A$.  That is, the sum of all the values of the Hadamard product equals the above trace values.  And if all the components of $A$ and $B$ happen to be positive, then $\sum_{j=1}^p |A_j \circ B_j| = trace(A \cdot B^\top) = trace(B \cdot A^\top)$

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The colon product is a convenient way to write the trace
$$B:A = A:B = \operatorname{Tr}\left(A^TB\right)
=\sum_i\sum_j A_{ij}B_{ij}$$
Define an element-wise sign function 
$$\eqalign{
\operatorname{sign}(X_{ij}) &= \begin{cases}
+1\quad&{\rm if\;}X_{ij}\ge 0 \\
-1\quad&{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases} \\
S &= \operatorname{sign}(X) \\
}$$
and use it to write the $\ell_1$-norm as 
$$\eqalign{
\|X\|_1 &= S:X \\
 &= \operatorname{Tr}(S^TX) \\
 &= \operatorname{Tr}(X^TS) \\
}$$ 
If all elements of the $X$ matrix are positive, then $S$ is the all-ones matrix and
$$\|X\|_1 = \operatorname{Tr}\left({\tt1}^TX\right)$$
And of course, everything can be expressed in terms of $A$, $B$, and the Hadamard product.
$$\eqalign{
X &= A\circ B \\
S &= \operatorname{sign}(A)\circ\operatorname{sign}(B) \\
}$$